# including more than one report.items value in the report header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Iam working on SSRS 2008.

I have a report that has 5 groupings and it consists of subtotal at all these group levels:
1.category level
2.product level
3.repname level
4.branch level
5.region level

But, branch level and region level groups have page breaks.i.e) Branch subtotal is in a new pagw  and region sub total is in a new page.All other group subtotals are in the same page.

I have included a text box in the table in the body section of the report and made it invisible.This text box is named as 'RR' and contains repregion value.And i refer to this text box in the header repregion box as

ReportItems!RR.Value

Hence until there is a pagebreak,this repregion value appears in the header.
BUt for branch subtotal or repregion subtotal, this value does not appear.

I tried to create another text box beside branch subtotal and access that from the header,buit it was not possible.!IS there any other way to solve this issue?

In short:

I want the repregion to appear in all pages(IN the header) even when there is a page break.

help needed

Answer (score 0):

Data regions are not allowed in header, only Textbox, Line, Image, Rectangle

Comment: But you can refer to data regions in these text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to refer to more than one report item in the header or footer. I overlapped the text boxes and this works fine when exported to pdf